# how to compare number of rows in redirected text file C

Tags: c, stderr

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char address[BUFFERSIZE];

    //checking text file on stdin which does not work
    if (fgets(address, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) < 42)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "The program needs at least 42 addresses for proper functionality.");
    }

    //while reads the redirected file line by line and print the content line by line
    while(fgets(address, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", address);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hi, this is my code. Does not work. The problem is that I have a redirected external file `adresy.txt` into stdin and I need to check if the file has the required number of rows.

The minimum number of rows that a file must have is 42. If it has 42 or more rows the program can continue, if not, it throws out the `fprintf(stderr, "The program needs at least 42 addresses for proper functionality.");`

I tried it this way `if (fgets(address, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) < 42)` but it still tells me that I can not compare pointer and integer 
like so: `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`

In the code extension I will compare the arguments from the user to what is in `adresy.txt` therefore I need `argc` and `*argv []` but now i need to solve this.

Any advice how to fix it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you read the [reference for `fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)? It returns the first argument (which is a `char*`) on success (or `NULL` on failure), your comparison to 42 doesn't make sense here (especially considering that `address` can only hold up to 10 characters)

Comment: If a file name is specified, it can be counted in advance by setting it to 2 PATH(In other words, read the file twice).
Since it is not known whether standard input(`stdin`) can `rewind`, After storing 42 words, decide the operation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code:

1. `#define BUFFERSIZE 10` is odd as your lines but be at least 42 long.
2. you compare the pointer returned by `fgets` to 42 which is nonsense, BTW your compiler warned you.
3. With your method you actually display only one line out of two

---

You probably want this:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 200  // maximum length of one line

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char address[BUFFERSIZE];

    while(fgets(address, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL)
    {
      // here the line has been read 

      if (strlen(address) < 42)
      {
          // if the length of the string read is < 42, inform user and stop

          fprintf(stderr, "The program needs at least 42 addresses for proper functionality.");
          exit(1);
      }

      // otherwise print line
      printf("%s", address);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and probably not with a `BUFFERSIZE = 10` :o

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks for that correction. Now it check if the length of string is greater than 100 (also needed that (thanks)), but it didn't meet my requirements. I may have misunderstood the problem. But what i need is to check if the number on lines are more than 42.

Comment: @PatrikLeško I'm not sure what you're asking in your last comment.